# How to show complete scale/all datapoints on X-axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Not sure if `scale` is the right word here, I have plotted a [chart here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/fsWG5/6/) that actually has 52 datapoints. I would like to show all of those on X-axis. I tried:

```
.ticks(52)
```

but that didnt help.

How do I show all dates on X-axis?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/fsWG5/6/)

Comment: Are you referring to showing all dates on the `xAxis` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `chart.xAxis.tickValues([pass and array of dates])`

The following code works on you chart. Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/vfe2B/).

```
chart.xAxis.tickValues(function(d) {
    var dateSets = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < d[0]['values'].length; i++) {
        dateSets.push(d[0]['values'][i]['0'])
    }
    return dateSets
});
```

It looks all too close together, so you might have to think of showing only the days and months may be in the xAxis. by formatting the date.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544859/how-to-update-nvd3-line-chart-with-additional-series